# Expanding Resolution of Data in Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a data frame with monthly frequency. 
The index is timestamped as 1880-01-01, 1880-02-01...
I'd like to expand the index to 1880-01-01, 1880-01-02...

Once this is done, I'd like to forward fill the data in the columns so that it repeats itself until the next datum is available.

The goal of this procedure is to then merge this data frame with other data frames that have daily resolution.

Comment: Can you do `print(dataframe.head())` and paste here what you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`Resampler.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.ffill.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[1,3]}, index=pd.to_datetime(['1880-01-01','1880-02-01']))

print (df)
            col
1880-01-01    1
1880-02-01    3

df1 = df.resample('d').ffill()
print (df1)

            col
1880-01-01    1
1880-01-02    1
1880-01-03    1
1880-01-04    1
1880-01-05    1
1880-01-06    1
1880-01-07    1
1880-01-08    1
1880-01-09    1
1880-01-10    1
...
```